# Some properties from database are null when they have value

Tags: c#, .net, linq

I'm trying to make works a login functionality but for some users `Linq` return some values as null when they have a correct value in database. For other users everything works ok.

This is my `linq`

```
public Clientes Login(string username) 
{
    DataClasses1DataContext db = new DataClasses1DataContext();
    var query = from c in db.Clientes
                where c.NroDocumento == username
                select c;
    return query.FirstOrDefault();
}
```

Then in the service layer I have the following:

```
Clientes o = userData.Login(username);
return (o != null && password == o.Password) 
    ? new UserEntity(o.CodCliente, o.Email, o.Empresa) 
    : null;
```

But when I debug, for some users I can see that the property `o.Password` has a value, and for others it appears as `null`.

The users are being created by other systems, so I don't know if that can impact, but when I run the Select directly in SQL Server, both users has a Password, so I don't understand which is the difference that makes Linq return null.

This is the image of the model (sorry for the spanish)

[image]

Comment: Could there be duplicates? You're selecting FirstOrDefault, which if there are 2 or more records, will return you only the first 1 it comes across, which may have no password. If you debug and see what 'var query' holds that might show this issue

Comment: Is this right where c.NroDocumento == username ?

Comment: Please show your Clientes class, Clientes mapping and a sample data in the database. It's hard to guess what's going on without proper examination of your entity.

Comment: One thing yo might want to check is if the passed in username has some extra whitespace characters which might be causing it to fail matching the username?

Comment: What is `userData`?

Comment: @sr28 sadly that was the answer :( Could you added as response so I can check it?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As per the comments it looks like there are duplicates, but some of them don't have a password. As you're using 'FirstOrDefault' in some cases it's picking up the one without a password.

Comment: If there should not be duplicates, you should consider using SingleOrDefault rather than FirstOrDefault.